# ConTeXt: Typeset XML attribute containing newlines

Tags: context, lua, parsing, xml

## Background

A user can provide their address information in a text area, separating lines by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. An XML document is generated, which replaces the new line character with `\n`, such as in the following document:

```xml
<html>
 <head>
  <title>The Mill on the Floss</title>
  <meta name="phone" content="" />
  <meta name="address" content="221B Baker St.\nLondon, U.K." />
 </head>
 <body>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

## Problem

I'd like to typeset the address information, based on the metadata attribute, honouring the new line. (Aside, it's possible to emit a new line character into the attribute [i.e., `\u000D`] directly, but the new line appears to be swallowed by ConTeXt when slurping up the XML document, so an escaped value is provided instead.)

## Code

I've tried many variations on a theme to write the address verbatim:

```tex
\startluacode
function xml.functions.address( t ) 
  lxml.attribute( t, "/html/head/meta[@name='address']", "content", "" )
end
\stopluacode
```

Replace the `lxml.attribute` line with attempts such as the following, combined with many different "LPATH" paths:

- `context( xml.attribute( t, "./", "content", "" ) )`
- `context( t.at[0] )`
- `context( t.at.content )`
- `context( xml.filter( t, "/attribute(label)" ) )`

The data is present because the following prove it:

- `for k,v in pairs(t) do context(v) end` -- writes many elements.
- `context( t )` -- writes the document metadata as shown in the following image (the `\` is missing):

[image: meta content]

Here is the setup:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:address
  \gdef\TextAddress{\xmlfunction{#1}{address}}
\stopxmlsetups
```

And the usage:

```tex
\startsetups document:start
  \startstandardmakeup
    \startalignment[middle]
      \TextAddress
    \stopalignment
  \stopstandardmakeup
\stopsetups
```

## Question

How would you retrieve the XHTML's address metadata content attribute and assign it to a macro that can be written to the document, honouring all new line characters?

...

Alternatively, how would you structure the document metadata to include multi-line address information such that LMTX can handle typesetting the newlines?

Comment: when parsed as xml a newline in an attribute value is lost, so you probably? would want to write it as `&#10;` rather than as an actual newline character. (that is as specified by XML, not tex or context specific)

Comment: That's a good idea. JSoup automatically converts entities in attributes, though. Using `&#10;` causes an actual new line control character to be written to the XHTML document. Using `&newline;` causes `&amp;newline;` to be written. There doesn't appear to be a way to disable this for attribute definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly ugly solution follows.

In the code that generates the address attribute value, replace all new line characters with a `\break{}` command (`\hfil` is probably not needed). For example, in Java:

```java
string.replaceAll( "\n", "\\\\\\break{}" );
```

This will make it through any entity barriers that the XHTML exporter code has in place, with the disadvantage of coupling the document to TeX. (Using `\\` or `\newline` would couple the code to a specific TeX implementation.) The output document contains:

```xml
<meta name="address" content="221B Baker St.\break{}London, U.K." />
```

Create a Lua function that writes the attribute value to the document. Accomplish this by dereferencing the table's `at` value using the XHTML meta element's attribute key name (in this case `content`):

```tex
\startluacode
function xml.functions.address( t )
  context( t.at["content"] )
end
\stopluacode
```

From there, define a new macro as usual:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:address
  \gdef\TextAddress{\xmlfunction{#1}{address}}
\stopxmlsetups
```

A solution that avoids coupling TeX code to the XHTML document would be to export individual lines as enumerated address lines. For example:

```xml
<meta name="address1" content="221B Baker St." />
<meta name="address2" content="London, U.K." />
```

Such a solution has other drawbacks.